# Validating YAML file for duplicate list items with JSON-schema

Tags: yaml, json-schema-validator

Is there a way to validate duplicate list items in a yaml file using JSON-schema ?

Example `config.yaml`:

```
config:
  - key1: some_value
    payload: another_value

  - key1: some_value
    payload: another_value
```

When I load the above yaml file, I want to receive a validation error saying that `key1` is duplicated.

I tried looking up at the [JSON-schema](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhutton-json-schema-validation-01) and I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema has the `uniqueItems` keyword for this. This is a schema that asserts the array contains no duplicates.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "uniqueItems": true
}
```